# How to retrieve the Card details of a customer from stripe with only customerId

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to retrieve the customer card details, so that I can show the user saved card details. can anyone please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that no one knows your project and if you want to get help from people you need to write more information, examples, what have you tried and where do you think the app is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done server-side with your secret key, and you can use this API call to list all the Customer's payment methods: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list#list_payment_methods-customer